# Is it ethical to ask manager repeatedly after short interval for onsite opportunity?

Tags: manager, india, promotion, it-industry

I was added to a project a year ago and it was stated that there will definitely be some onsite opportunities later in project.

When I asked, manager told me he will put forward my name to upper management if anything arises. But when I asked for update, he said right now there are measures to cut costs and shift some focus offshore - and that the project was also not in a good state due to mismanagement.

Now, the project is going well with proper management and has couple of new offshore associates in the team. Additionally, they previously said the business is looking for more offshore team members and even though existing onsite folks still continue working.

is it the right time to ask again after 5 months, considering my experience with the team and how quickly I usually take ownership of work and resolve many issues? As if the management team is still not ready to promote, I can plan studies and move to another project or another good company.

Comment: I'm guessing from language and context clues that you might be based in India, and in a particular offshore / onshore work situation. Can you tag the post accordingly, or with the correct country and other details on the situation if I guessed wrong. On the question, my brief answer-in-a-comment: It's ethical, it just might be annoying to ask for the same thing frequently after being turned down. But it's been a whole year, so it's not exactly pestering.

Comment: Yes I belong to India and your assumption is correct

Comment: @AdamBurke good suggestions for location and context. However, please don't answer in comments, post an answer instead as comments are not for that (and can be deleted any time)

Comment: What is a short interval? A year, half a year. a month? A week? A day, an hour? Please add some specificity here.

Answer (score 6):

"If you don't ask, you don't get"

These are words I've lived by. In most situations when I know I'm being cheeky and trying it on, I get a polite 'No' - in which case, I drop it move on and make a witty remark about it was worth a shot.

Sometimes though, it works.

Now - to address the question under the question - which is 'How short an interval is too short' - In terms of general BAU - I would say that asking for something more than once a Month is probably too much.

But that isn't always the case - If there's been a change in circumstances, then it might be appropriate to ask sooner:

"Hey Boss, at the company all hands, it was announced we had secured some investor funding and Project X is now going full-steam ahead, I know I asked a week ago about this project - but seeing as things have substantially changed in the Business, I'd like to revisit this"

Inversely - if you know that there are still significant issues in the business, asking again in a Month might not be prudent e.g. If they have had to freeze all new hiring, then they announce they aren't going to back-fill existing roles, it's a good indicator that times are tough and asking again isn't a good option.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR -** There's no harm in asking. However, use your best judgement to express the ask with a professional wrapper, not to appear as nagging. When asking for the opportunity, also present how the company and team will benefit if you are provided with the opportunity you asked for - do not get into "demand" mode, without having a justification for the company to consider you as a candidate for your ask.

To elaborate, you did not mention when was the last time you asked, and whether you were told / promised any timeline when the options will open up as per your requirement - however, if you see that not getting the opportunity to work "onsite" is limiting your career, please concentrate on finding alternatives that suite your needs better.

Comment: Given the "repeatedly in a short interval" in the question, I would say, no harm in asking, likely harm to your prospects if you pester.

Comment: Edited question addresses your query and I was promised a year ago when project was just started and was not in good hands. Now project has come up from shore to mid sea and just will cross in couple of months. My Role in team - I am always attentive, responsible, help team members and quickly learn things and work on it.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it right time to ask again, and ethical to repeat as previously

I don't see anything unethical about a asking a simple question like this, but everyone's definition of "Ethics" is different (and also mostly irrelevant). If you previously asked last week, it would feel a bit repetitive but if your previous ask is a month or more ago, this would be a perfectly fine thing to do.

> When I asked for update, he said right now there is cost cutting and shifting more on offshore.

> they said business looking for more offshore team, even though existing onsite folks still continue working.

None of these sounds good, so you should prepare yourself for a negative or evasive answer. If that's what you get it may be time to start looking elsewhere. In this case, you have nothing much to lose, so can lean in a little harder: Ask about a specific career plan, measurable requirements and a time line. If your manager doesn't want to engage or remains evasive you have your answer: It's "no".